# Swift 4 way to fake existentials with protocols and `Self`

Tags: swift

There are hundreds of solutions to fake existentials in Swift with protocols and `Self`, but they mostly refer to Swift 2 and the bright future that Swift 3 might bring...
Now Swift 4 is out, with nice additions for Generics. But I couldn't find any suggestions how to fit that into the missing existentials problem.

Any Ideas how to solve this the Swift ***4*** way?

Example:

```
import UIKit

protocol Bla {
    func compare(other: Self)
}

extension CGFloat : Bla {
    func compare(other: CGFloat) {
        print("Extended CGFloat")
    }
}

extension UIEdgeInsets : Bla {
    func compare(other: UIEdgeInsets) {
        print("Extended UIEdgeInsets")
    }
}

/* Possible, but what if we want to CGFloat _and_ UIEdgeInsets inside here?
 Well, that would _not_ work! */
class Possible<T: Bla> {
    var array: [T]!
}

/* This is open to everything...
 And therefore fails to compile, no dynamic type info at runtime I guess. */
class Fail {
    var array: [Bla]!
}

// Works, but I don't need that.
let list = Possible<CGFloat>()

// I need that:
let list = Fail()
let f: CGFloat = 1.23
let edge = UIEdgeInsets()
list.array.append(f)
list.array.append(edge)
```

Comment: In your comment "but what if we want to CGFloat _and_ UIEdgeInsets inside here? Well, that would _not_ work!", could you explain what do you mean?

Comment: @AhmadF I added code under the "I need that:" comment to show what I mean.

Comment: There are good answers below (the short answer: what you're describing can't currently be done), but as described, how would this be useful? What are we to make of "an array of CGFloats and UIEdgeInsets?" What could you do with such a thing without eventually resorting back to `as?` casting (which generally suggests you've done something wrong). In almost all cases of questions like this, it is critical to know the actual requirement, and to make sure that requirement is really a *requirement* for this problem and not just "I want the code to be as generic as possible."

Comment: Note that none of the Swift 4 changes to generics change the underlying problems here. The Swift 3 answers are completely applicable to Swift 4.

Comment: @RobNapier Thanks. If you are sure about the non-improving part about Swift 4 you could post that as an answer and I will mark that as the correct answer. Plus: I think for my specific example there were also no improvements in Swift 2 -> 3. I feared that, sad to be right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift 4 didn't make any generics changes that address this issue. For the full roadmap, see the [Generics Manifesto](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md). That said, the protocol you're describing is equivalent to `Equatable`, and so would have all the same problems. There is no current roadmap to create what you're describing. The closest is discussed at the very end of the Manifesto, in the section called "Opening existentials."

As you've described the problem, it isn't clear how it would be useful, so I suspect your actual problem is different. You should go back to your actual program and consider what its real requirements are. For example, if your real requirement is "an array of CGFloat or UIEdgeInsets" that is absolutely buildable in Swift. "An array" translates to `[T]`, and "OR" translates to `enum` (Swift's "sum type" in type theory parlance). So what you mean is:

```
enum Element {
    case scalar(CGFloat)
    case insets(UIEdgeInsets)
}
let list: [Element]
```

That is completely different than "an array of things that can be compared to themselves." If, on the other hand, you really mean "an array of value-like things," then that also is pretty easy to build in Swift with `NSValue` (and its subclass, `NSNumber`):

```
class Things {
    var array: [NSValue] = []

    func append(_ value: CGFloat) {
        array.append(NSNumber(value: Double(value)))
    }

    func append(_ insets: UIEdgeInsets) {
        array.append(NSValue(uiEdgeInsets: insets))
    }
}

let list = Things()
let f: CGFloat = 1.23
let edge = UIEdgeInsets()
list.append(f)
list.append(edge)

list.array[0] == list.array[0]  // true
list.array[0] == list.array[1]  // false
```

Comment: Big thanks, that was an exhaustive answer, link and where to look was really informative :-) . And yes: My actual problem is more complex. I just thought of Java, where this `interface Number {
    Number add(Number input);
}` works perfectly fine with
`class NumberContainer {
    List<Number> testList = new ArrayList<Number>();
}` because: Runtime type info.

Comment: That doesn't look like the same protocol as your Swift example. The equivalent I think would be `protocol Bla { func compare(other: Bla) }`, which I don't think would have any of the problems you're encountering (since it has no `Self` requirement), and would basically work like Java I believe.

Comment: And... Upvoted your comment. That is 100% correct. You were right, pointed me in the right direction and I found a much better solution for my problem :-)

Answer (score 3):

Fundamentally, it can't be done. If you could have:

```
class Fail {
    var array: [Bla]!
}
```

You could then try to write code like this:

```
func compareAll(foo: Fail)
{
    for x in foo.array
    {
        x.compare(other: y)
    }
}
```

What type is `y`? The protocol says it has to be the same type as the object adopting the protocol but you don't know the type of `x` until runtime. There is no way to write that code with y being both a `UIEdgeInsets` and a `CGFloat` at the same time.

I think you could make it work by removing the dependency on `Self` by making `compare` generic. Your protocol would look like this:

```
protocol Bla {
    func compare<T: Bla>(other: T)
}
```

Implementations of `compare` would have to test the type of `other` and cast to the right type.

```
extension CGFloat: Bla 
{
    func compare<T: Bla>(other: T) 
    { 
        if let casted = other as? CGFloat
        {
            // do whatever
        }
    }
}
```

I think this approach is better than using type erasure (see Daniel Hall's answer) for a couple of reasons:

- There's no overhead of having to wrap everything in a wrapper object or the indirection of `compare`.
- The `compare` function  can work when `other` is an arbitrary type, not just the same type of `self` if it makes sense e.g.

  ```
  func compare<T: Bla>(other: T) 
  { 
      if let casted = other as? CGFloat
      {
          // do whatever
      }
      else if let casted = other as? UIEdgeInsets
      {
          // Do something else
      }
  }
  ```

Of course, if you are simply given the protocol and you can't change it, type erasure is your only option.

Answer (score 2):

This is typically handled with a type eraser, for example:

```
struct AnyBla: Bla {
  private let compareClosure: (Any) -> ()  
  func compare(other: AnyBla) {
    compareClosure(other)
  }
  init<T: Bla>(_ bla: T) {
    compareClosure = { 
        if let other = $0 as? T {
          bla.compare(other: other)
        } else {
          print("Can't compare type \(type(of: bla)) with \(type(of: $0))")
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you would change your array to any array of the type eraser, i.e.

```
class Fail {
    var array: [AnyBla]!
}
```

Then you can accomplish what you want to do like this:

```
let list = Fail()
let f: CGFloat = 1.23
let edge = UIEdgeInsets()
list.array.append(AnyBla(f))
list.array.append(AnyBla(edge))
```